# How to execute a Ctrl+,,f keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I am trying to execute a keyboard shortcut noted as `Ctrl+,,f`
The shortcut is meant to evaluate a script by sublimeREPL in Sublime Text 3.

What exactly should I press on the keyboard? I tried holding `Ctrl` and then pressing the comma key two times and then the f key. I also tried holding all the keys, but I every time I try, I get the find box triggered.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chording). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, then <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: I would add that you need to press Ctrl and Comma at once, release them and then press f immediately.